# C# HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader () NOT WORKING

Tags: c#, html, .net, pdf

I have a problem with downloading pdf files.

This is my code in c# :

```
     string file = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/FOLDER1/FOLDER2/test.pdf");
       HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename=\"{0}.pdf\"", "GGG"));
       HttpContext.Current.Response.WriteFile(file, false);
       HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

It seems like `HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition`, `string.Format("attachment; filename=\"{0}.pdf\"", "GGG"));"` is not working.

Instead of downloading the file it displays something like this:

x��V}p��۽ۻ�����7�%��.9H�|   �����p+w���^B�Z* A��甶Z;���3L�-3-�X�S�t�#S�v:-�~�X�ZK��y�}/��������}��}>~ϳ���$���E���7?���������} �����p4:�z\����9�����b;���X���pP~�+q�둰å| �{p}]"�'ӡ���&� ռ��#�~��H�9�����}��̴���0`+u�mS�����`�,��B/.�A��. x���������<�dlls����Elp׷ɷa� ��]���vW_��n}\��ҁY2n�ar���N3VZ��٬t���6���.��Q�u���`s��� �^���-�+�*+ʙ�9�+�$åׯ��{��e�~>�<�|�/

/ArialBold /Encoding /Identity-H /DescendantFonts [43 0 R] /ToUnicode 44 0 R>> endobj 2 0 obj << /Type /Pages /Kids [ 5 0 R ] /Count 1 /ProcSet [/PDF

I also tried to downlad an image but the problem remains.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: did you ever set content type?  `HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"`

Comment: yes, I add:  HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");  before :            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename=\"{0}.pdf\"", "GGG"));

Answer (score 0):

try something like that:

```
string file=HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/FOLDER1/FOLDER2/test.pdf");
MemoryStream stream= new MemoryStream();
HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;            
response.ClearContent();
response.Clear();
response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename=\"{0}.pdf\""));
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write))
 {
     stream.WriteTo(fs);
 }

 response.Flush();
 response.End();
```